# How to insert and delete objects in json file swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

So I have this json which has an array of some objects.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "First Object"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Second Object"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Third Object"
    }
]
```

I'm parsing the json with the following code,

```
struct MyModel: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let title: String?
}

var myModel = [MyModel]()

func decodeData(url: URL) {
    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        myModel = try decoder.decode([MyModel].self, from: jsonData)
    } catch let jsonError {
        print("Error serializing json", jsonError)
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when it comes to reading the json. What I can seem to figure out is how to delete and insert object into the same json file.

For example, delete object with "id"=2, or insert a new object after object with "id"=3 or between objects with "id"=1 and "id"=2.

What I was thinking was to read the entire json file into an array. Then modify the data in the array by deleting and appending elements in the array then overwriting the json file with everything in the modified array.

For some reason this approach doesn't seem practical. Might be fine for a small numbers of objects but what happens if/when the number of objects reach a number in the 100+ range.

Am I taking the right approach by reading the contents of the json file into an array then modifying and overwriting the json file with the contents of the modify array or is there a proper way of achieving this?

Comment: Re-writing he whole file is pretty much the only way you can do it. Even 100+ items isn't a lot, but you may want to consider whether this is the best way to store your data. Core Data or some other data store might be better

Comment: Been looking at documentation and tutorials for core data but can't seem to wrap my head around it but at the same time I want to learn more on how to deal with json with swift so it's more of a learning exercise.

Comment: Can always use something like SwiftyJSON for East Jain serialization and element handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete any object from Dictionary using this piece of code, convert json to Dictionary.

```
if let index = values.index(forKey: id) {
   values.remove(at: index)
}
```

and in the same way you can get the index of particular object where you want to insert new object.